# sendKeys stops the e2e test flow in Protractor

Tags: protractor, angular-e2e

I have the following code:

```
const inputBoxes = await landingPage.getPortIdInputBox();
await inputBoxes[0].sendKeys('0040');
await inputBoxes[1].sendKeys('9142');

const url: string = await browser.getCurrentUrl();

expect(url).toContain('/profile?fund1=0040&fund2=9142');
```

I am writing e2e test cases for my Angular 6 app with Protractor and Jasmine, all the tests seem to be running fine but at times the flow stops after entering the text into the input boxes.
It stops for around a minute and then successfully confirms the result.
I have 2 methods that checks for the user inputs by using `sendKeys` method form `WebdriverJS`, sometimes the flow stops in the first function and at times it stops in the second function after entering the text in the input box.

I am even using `async/awaut` to take care of the promises returned by the `WebdriverJS` methods. This is resulting in the build getting failed in the CD pipeline with the following error:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Not sure where I am going wrong. Locally all the tests pass well within the timeout range but they fail in the CD pipeline.

Here's my protractor.conf.js file:

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
const JUnitXmlReporter = require('jasmine-reporters').JUnitXmlReporter;
const ENV = require('../variables.js');
const path = require('path');
const tsNode = require('ts-node');

exports.config = {
  logLevel: 'DEBUG',
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  getPageTimeout: 120000,
  specs: [path.join(__dirname, 'src', '**/*.e2e-spec.ts')],
  directConnect: ENV.PROTRACTOR_DIRECT_CONNECT,
  multiCapabilities: ENV.PROTRACTOR_MULTI_CAPABILITIES,
  seleniumAddress: ENV.PROTRACTOR_SELENIUM_ADDRESS,
  chromeDriver: ENV.PROTRACTOR_CHROME_DRIVER,
  resultJsonOutputFile: ENV.TEST_E2E_REPORT_FILE,
  baseUrl: ENV.BASE_URL,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    tsNode.register({ project: path.join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json') });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: ENV.TEST_E2E_REPORT_DIRECTORY
      })
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: can we take a look at your config? tag me please when you upload it

Comment: try different version of `chrome` on CD

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I have added protractor.conf.js file

Comment: Still not enough information. But to save our time I'll post my guess and if it'll work I'll post full information about the solution. In my **conf.js** I have `capabilities` obj, where I specify my browser as `"browserName": "chrome"` and that object takes property `"chromeOptions"` which in turn takes `"args"`. The value of `"args"` property is an array of arguments for chrome to execute it with. So that array must include "--no-sandbox" argument in order to start tests from host. IT WON'T WORK WITHOUT IT. If you can't figure out what to do, post your `ENV.PROTRACTOR_CHROME_DRIVER`